# How to prevent from value substitution for variables in angular 6 buil files

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm using angular 6 in my application, I just want to know is there any angular build config property to prevent the value substitution instead of using variable and also for minifing the variable names in the final build file.

For Example:

If my code in component.ts look like this

```
let func = sampleFunct(firstname,lastname);
```

I want my code to look like this in build file

```
let a = b(c,d);
```

Existing, how its working is in build file is

```
let func = sampleFunct('abc','def');
```

It is substituting the value of the variables instead of using the minified variables.

My angular.json configuraion look like this

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
}
```

Kindly provide a way to prevent this to happen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem is it causing?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried 'ng build --prod'? This `--prod` option should uglify (i.e. obfuscate) your code.